# how to setup separate desktop session to laptop from TV

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv

My wife and I need the laptop but we have only one. Actually I have an office laptop too which is crap but I can't let her browse on that. The laptop runs Windows 8.1/Ubuntu 14.10 dual boot. I also have an old basic 22" LCD TV with 2 USB and 2 HDMI ports but no Wireless connectivity. I was wondering if one of us login to laptop directly and the other one login to laptop indirectly from the TV at the same time?

Note:

- It's not desktop mirroring I want. I can do that already with an HDMI
  cable. The windows or ubuntu session on the TV and the laptop should
  be separate sessions.
- I guess I will need some hardware to connect a
  keyboard and a mouse when logging in from TV. What hardware would I
  need?
- The extra hardware on TV should possibly support WiFi because the laptop and the TV are in different rooms. I want to avoid a physical HDMI cable connection.
- I am okay with running a VNC session and accessing that on the TV(along with additional keyboard,mouse)

Update:
I finally used an old android tablet to connect to TV via HDMI and run VNC viewer to stream a VNC session from the laptop. I still need to check if wireless keyboard/mouse would work with this tablet. One more problem still is that screen on the table and the TV are still mirror images. It is not possible to extend the screen to TV and turn off the tablet display.

Comment: I don't think that setup will work, i.e. the TV won't be able to work as a client since it's really just a screen with some added features. You might have to add another device like a smartphone to be used with remote desktop/VNC stuff.

Comment: @Mario I am looking at something like Google Chromecast. But as I understand chromecast only does desktop mirroring.

Comment: Chromecast is more like live-streaming, yes. What's your goal? Play games on the TV? Or just surfing the web a bit?

Comment: Far, far easier and simpler to buy her a secondhand laptop - Cheaper too. I recently picked up a dual core HP complete for $60 on eBay and it runs Lubuntu (Lightweight Ubuntu) beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an Windows in Application Server role.

And you're in luck!!!! Having windows 8 means it is at all possible. I don't know how to do it on Ubuntu, but wouldn't be surprised there is a way as well...

Here's how. However, as it's quite... non-mainstream, you're in a world of work on your own.

http://www.wegotserved.com/2012/07/03/building-windows-8-home-server-introduction/

EDIT: I think you would do what you need way faster with Android TV box, though.